# How to hide specific item from a combo box in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I hide specific number of items from a combo box. Code below will hide all the items instead. I couldn't find a way to perform this

```
string taskSelection = taskSelectionComboBox.Text;
string stateOfChild = stateOfChildComboBox.Text;
if (stateOfChild == "Awake")
{
    taskSelectionComboBox.Hide();
}
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly! - You can't. You need to remove and re-aadd.. Is the combobox data-bound? what are those items? string?

Comment: @TaW, yes it's winforms and those are strings thanx anyway fixed it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to store the items you want then use remove method to delete them. you can use add to make them back.

```
// keep the items in a list
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Awake");
// remove them from combobox
comboBox1.Items.Remove("Awake");
// if you want to add them again.
comboBox1.Items.Add(list[0]);
```

Comment: This will work if the Item is really just a string. If it is an object you need a slightly different code. And if it is data-bound you still need a different way..

Comment: correct but i think he just wants to remove strings not more. it also works for integers

Comment: Thank you @MasoudMohammadi explaining simply . I was able to fix this

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you to look at [`DrawItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`MeasureItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.measureitem(v=vs.110).aspx) events and just make your logic in it.

```
// this is crucial as it gives the the measurement and drawing capabilities
// to the item itself instead of a parent ( ComboBox )
taskSelectionComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;

taskSelectionComboBox.DrawItem +=TaskSelectionDrawItem;
taskSelectionComboBox.MeasureItem += TaskSelectionMeasureItem;
```

Then inside of `TaskSelectionMeasureItem` method just set height to `0` :

```
void TaskSelectionMeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(/* check if you want to draw item positioned on index e.Index */
        !CanDraw(e.Index) // or whatever else to determine
    )
        e.ItemHeight = 0;
}
```

After that in the drawing method ( `TaskSelectionDrawItem` ) you can check for that again and either draw or not that particular element :

```
void TaskSelectionDrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(CanDraw(e.Index))
    {
        Brush foregroundBrush = Brushes.Black;
        e.DrawBackground();
        e.Graphics.DrawString(
            taskSelectionComboBox.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
            e.Font,
            foregroundBrush,
            e.Bounds,
            StringFormat.GenericDefault
        );
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

Comment: @m.rogalski thank you for the answer. Although it's bit complex for me this might be a better way than the one in above but. i just needed a simple way to do it. Any way thanx man

Answer (score 4):

Another approach will be using `DataSource` of combobox

```
var originalTasks = new List<string>
{
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Awake"
};

taskSelectionComboBox.DataSource = originalTasks;
```

Then you will hide items by re-assigning `DataSource` with only items you want to show

```
taskSelectionComboBox.DataSource = originalTasks.Where(item => item != "Awake").ToList();
```

An show all items back again

```
taskSelectionComboBox.DataSource = originalTasks;
```

This approach will work for any types of items.

Comment: quite interesting and clean approach. Thank you man!. still i couldn't give a vote up my bad

Comment: This does not actually "hide" the items but just essentially just sets them to a new collection in the ComboBox and then sets again back to what they were originally

Answer (score 1):

Based on the very neat method of my colleague Mateusz:
The items displayed in comboBox need not be text strings, but any objects having a ToString () method that outputs as an item.
We can introduce an additional Hidden property into such an object. Then, in the described methods, add recognition of this property and quite naturally eliminate the display of this item.

Replace

```
if (CanDraw(e.Index))
{
}
```

with

```
object item = combo.Items[e.Index];
var h = item.GetType().GetProperty("Hidden");
if (!(h == null) && h.GetValue(item).AsBool())
{

}
```