# Populate Combo Box with only results that start with selected items first character from another combo box

Tags: c#, string, winforms, list, combobox

I have two combo boxes `comboBox1` & `comboBox2`. comboBox1 is populated like so:

```
 BindingSource comboBox1Bs = new BindingSource();

comboBox1Bs.DataSource = new List<string> { "Apple","Amber","Book","Bean","Cat","Cook"};
comboBox1.DataSource = comboBox1Bs;
```

Combo Box Two is like so:

```
 BindingSource comboBox2Bs = new BindingSource();

comboBox2Bs.DataSource = new List<string> { "Aresult","Bresult","Cresult"};
comboBox2.DataSource = comboBox2Bs;
```

When a selection from combo box 1 is made I only want results starting with the same letter as the selected to show in combo box 2. For example if Apple is selected only Aresult will show (but if there were more results being with A they would also show).

To get the starting letter from comboBox1 I have the following:

```
var prefix = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
```

But what can I add so combox2 will only show results that start with the same as the contents of `prefix`

Comment: Currently I can think of two options : **1)** Operate on `DataSource` and just remove unwanted entries or add the ones you want. **2)** Apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758727/how-to-hide-specific-item-from-a-combo-box-in-win-forms/45759080#45759080) which will give you the possibility to show or hide elements in your `ComboBox` **AD.** instead of substring you could do `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()[0] + "";`

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks will check it out. (PS don't want to be off topic but I see english is not your first lanuage, on your profile's first line you should swap the word 'thought' with 'taught')

Comment: Yes English is not my first language but I'm still learning :) Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the collection in the list so that you can filter it:

```
List<string> colComboBox_2 = new List<string> { "Aresult","Bresult","Cresult"};
```

then you can filter it when you have your prefix:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var prefix = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
    comboBox2.DataSource = colComboBox_2.Where(x => x.StartsWith(prefix)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: There's no `toList()` method in C# Linq and assignment requires `=` sign meaning this wont even compile.

Comment: @m.rogalski you could have just corrected the typo by an edit :) probably would have taken less time than writing this comment ;) thanx for the pointing out though. Was writing a little too hasty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to achieve that.

```
List<string> foo = ((List<string>)comboBox2Bs.DataSource).Where(x => x.().Substring(0, 1).StartsWith(prefix));

comboBox2.DataSource = foo;
```

The following example should be even better

```
List<string> foo = ((List<string>)comboBox2Bs.DataSource).Where(x => x.ToString().StartsWith(prefix));
comboBox2.DataSource = foo;
```

Comment: Usage of `Substring` is not required when you're using `StartsWith` method. It would be more readable without it.

Comment: Looks good but I get the error: Bindingsourse does not contain a defition for Where and no extion method Where accpeting a first argument of Typle BindSoucre could be found I have using System.Linq;

Comment: Fixed the issue

Comment: the second example leads to a `System.ArgumentException` because you are missing the `ToList` call after the `Where`