# How can hide or visible false an item from Combo Box in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How can hide or visible false an item from Combo Box in c# windows form?
I tried this code in event selectedIndexChange

```
Switch (myComboBox.selectedIndex)
{
     Case 0:
         Visible=false;
      break;
}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not valid C# code. C# is case sensitive.

Comment: This code hide raddropdown list. But i want hide an item of raddropdownlist.

Comment: duplicated [How to hide specific item from a combo box in win forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45758727/4977870)

Answer (score 0):

To hide an item in ComboBox

```
// keep the items in a list
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("city");

// remove them from combobox
comboBox1.Items.Remove("city");

// if you want to add them again.
comboBox1.Items.Add(list[0]);
```

Comment: This code is for enable item , not for hide or visible false item.

Comment: I use this control in c# winform